# How to get rid of document.write from this Blogger widget

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I'm working on a Blogger widget, trying to rid it of any deprecated or bad practices (based what I read on Stack Overflow), such as `document.write`

This was working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function introductory(json) {
        document.write('<div id="intro-wrapper">');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            var introTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
            var introContent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
            var item = '<h2>' + introTitle + '</h2><p>' + introContent + '</p>';
            document.write(item);
        }
     document.write('</div>');
    }
</script>
<script src="https://MYBLOG.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/intro?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=introductory"></script>
```

It displays the title and content (wrapped up within `h2` and `p` tags, respectively) of *one* single post ( `...max-results=1...` ), labeled "intro" ( `.../-/intro?...` ) by means of Blogger labels.

I've tested various alternatives, lining up my html elements prior to the js, then using `getElementById`, followed by either `innerHTML` or `appendChild`, or even lining up the elements *inside* the js, by means of `createElement`, but to no avail, really. Would it be possible for anyone to point me to the right direction?

**P.S.** I can hardly copy and paste all of my attempts in this question. There have been dozens of them, as I'm more or less clueless when it comes to javascript and I'm just experimenting my way forwards, so I've opted for merely posting the code that is actually working and asking for an alternative that does *not* utilize `document.write`, if that's indeed "bad practice".

Comment: why would `document.write` be deprecated or bad practice?

Comment: @giorgio There are numerous threads here on Stack Overflow that suggest it is... I'm just reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I greet you at the beginning about trying to rid `document.write`

Create an element with a unique id **before** your JS code in the document, then select this element by its id `getElementById` and add your content to it using `innerHTML`

```
<div id="intro-wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function introductory(json) {
        var item="";
        for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            var introTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
            var introContent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
            item += '<h2>' + introTitle + '</h2><p>' + introContent + '</p>';
        }
     document.getElementById('intro-wrapper').innerHTML=item;
    }
</script>
<script src="https://MYBLOG.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/intro?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=introductory"></script>
```

Comment: I'm about to try this now. Could you please clarify the difference between plain `=` and `+=` ? I was also wondering if the div is really necessary, since Blogger seems to create a div for every widget that you add, e.g. `id = 'HTML4'`,,, May I just go ahead and `get` *that* `ElementById` ?

Comment: Okay! So, this works, even without the div: `document.getElementById('widget-id').innerHTML = item;` Thanks a lot! What's with `var item = "";` ? It seems to be the extra line that's doing the magic...

Comment: I have declared the variable `var item = "";` outside the for loop to avoid changing its value by for loop also `item += '...';` = `item = item + '... ';` if you need to show more than one post.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `document.createElement` instead of `document.write`.

Here is working example -

```html
<script>
    function introductory(json) {
        var RecentPostContainer = document.createElement('div');
        RecentPostContainer.className = 'RecentPostContainer';

        for(i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {

            var PostContainer = document.createElement('div');
            PostContainer.className = 'PostContainer';

            var PostTitle = document.createElement('h2');
            PostTitle.className = 'PostTitle';
            var PostTitleText = document.createTextNode(json.feed.entry[i].title.$t);
            PostTitle.appendChild(PostTitleText);
            PostContainer.appendChild(PostTitle);

            var PostContent = document.createElement('div');
            PostContent.className = 'PostContent';
            PostContent.innerHTML = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
            PostContainer.appendChild(PostContent);

            RecentPostContainer.appendChild(PostContainer);

        }

        document.getElementById('RecentPostContainer').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', RecentPostContainer.outerHTML);
    }
</script>
<script id='RecentPostContainer' src="https://blogger.googleblog.com/feeds/posts/default/?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=introductory"></script>
```